# .htaccess help for folders?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to make pretty urls with htaccess..
I want's to make url `www.mysite.com/movie/name.html` from `www.mysite.com/movie/movie.php?url=name`

here movie/ is a folder, similarly I have two more folders like albums/ and news/ , I wants to make url`s like below

- www.mysite.com/albums/name.html from ww.mysite.com/albums/album.php?id=name
- www.mysite.com/news/name.html from ww.mysite.com/news/album.php?id=name

The .htaccess is below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# removing .php extension 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#Code to rewrite www.mysite.com/movie/name to www.mysite.com/movie/movie.php?url=name
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ movie.php?url=$1
</IfModule>
```

but I am getting every page redirected

please suggest proper code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^ - [S=3,L]

#www.mysite.com/movie/movie.php?url=name

RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]+)\.html?(.*)$ movie/movie.php?url=$1$2 [QSA,S=2,L]

#www.mysite.com/news/album.php?id=name

RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)\.html?(.*)$ news/album.php?id=$1$2 [QSA,S=1,L]

#www.mysite.com/albums/album.php?id=name

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html?(.*)$ $1/$2.php?id=$2$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Mohammad.....I can able to redirect but I am not able to GET parameter url....can u suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

to redirect php file use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/])/$ /$1.php [L]
```

and then for specific page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/])/([0-9]+)/([^/])\.html$ /$1.php?url=$2 [L,QSA]
```

you can check **Documentation** [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)